# looping through DS.FilteredRecordArray when the content becomes ready

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have my route defined like :

```
setupController: function (controller, model) {
    var analyticsRuns,
        store = this.get('store'),
        exerciseRunId = this.controllerFor('analyticsContext').get('exerciseRunId');

    // Query the server for all runs that belong to this exercise run.
    // The results of the query will be loaded into the store so we can start
    // filtering them, thus taking advantage of live updates.
    // (see http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/)
    store.find('analyticsRun', { 'exerciseRunId': exerciseRunId });

    analyticsRuns = store.filter('analyticsRun', function (analyticsRun) {
        return analyticsRun.get('exerciseRunId') === exerciseRunId;
    });

    controller.set('model', analyticsRuns);
    controller.set('exerciseRunId', exerciseRunId);
    controller.set('analyticsTemplates', store.find('analyticsTemplate'));
    controller.set('exerciseRun', store.find('exerciseRun',exerciseRunId));

    controller.send('setAnalyticsRunSelectOptions');
}
```

And in my controller action 'setAnalyticsRunSelectOptions' is defined as :

```
    setAnalyticsRunSelectOptions: function () {
        var options = [], run;
        //console.log(this.get('content'));
        //console.log(this.get('content.length'));

        //for(var i= 0,len=this.get('content.length');i<len;i++){
        //    run = this.get('content').objectAt(i);
        //    options.push({"id": run.get('id'), "label": run.get('id') + " " + run.get('name')});
        //}

        console.log(this.get('content'));
        this.get('model').forEach(function (run) {

            options.push({"id": run.get('id'), "label": run.get('id') + " " + run.get('name')});
        });

        this.set('analyticsRunSelectOptions',options);
    }
```

But when I log the "content" within that function in my firebug, it shows

**{ content=[0], store=, manager=, more...}**

but when I click on it(in firebug), the content can be seen there. I am thinking its because the content has not yet been populated when setAnalyticsRunSelectOptions is called. Is there a way to trigger my action only when the content becomes available??

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know when the `store.find('analyticsRun')` is loaded using the `then` method. So you will be able to loop in the loaded data.

The updated code is the following:

```
setupController: function (controller, model) {
    var analyticsRuns,
        store = this.get('store'),
        exerciseRunId = this.controllerFor('analyticsContext').get('exerciseRunId');

    // Query the server for all runs that belong to this exercise run.
    // The results of the query will be loaded into the store so we can start
    // filtering them, thus taking advantage of live updates.
    // (see http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/)
    store.find('analyticsRun', { 'exerciseRunId': exerciseRunId }).then(function() {
        controller.send('setAnalyticsRunSelectOptions'); 
    }); 

    analyticsRuns = store.filter('analyticsRun', function (analyticsRun) {
        return analyticsRun.get('exerciseRunId') === exerciseRunId;
    });

    controller.set('model', analyticsRuns);
    controller.set('exerciseRunId', exerciseRunId);
    controller.set('analyticsTemplates', store.find('analyticsTemplate'));
    controller.set('exerciseRun', store.find('exerciseRun',exerciseRunId));   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcio, that worked for me. I feel super stupid now because I was trying to do "then" on "analyticsRuns" variable before!

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the content of your controller in your `setupController` hook. Include the following line in `setupController`:

```
controller.set('content', model);
```